# converting a negative value to 0

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I am working with a datagrid view, this datagrid view allows the user to edit cells, I want to set it up so that when a user inserts a negative value, it will convert this value to 0, what would be the best way to code this, i have created the followin code below, it appears to check for negative values, however it does not change the value to zero

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) < -0)
                {
                   intQtyInsp = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                intQtyInsp = Int32.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: What is `intQtyInsp`? your code is incomplete, we can't understand what can goes wrong if you don't give more details

Comment: Qtyinsp is another cell, in which i want me zero value to go

Comment: Also, spacing and casing is important when discussing a computer language construct. A `DataGridView` is not the same as a `DataGrid` and/or a `View`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you require

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell currentCell = 
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    int cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(currentCell.Value);
    if (cellValue < 0)
        currentCell.Value = 0.ToString();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That might be because `dgvDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` and `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` might not be the same cell you are checking..

Comment: Also, he calls `Convert.ToInt32` on the first line but `Int32.Parse` on the last. These will usually produce the same value, but not always! (i.e. if the input isn't valid)

Answer (score 1):

```
intQtyInsp =Int32.Parse(dgvDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());

if(intQtyInsp < 0)
  {
     intQtyInsp = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(score < 0) { *score = 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a extension method to ensure if the user inputs a int.

#### Extension method

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static int TryConvertToInt32(this string value)
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value, out result))
            return result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
// call the extension method
int intQtyInsp = dgvDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString().TryConvertToInt32();

// And check for lower than zero values.
intQtyInsp = intQtyInsp >= 0 ? intQtyInsp : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int valueFromCell =  Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
intQtyInsp = valueFromCell < 0 
               ?  0
               : valueFromCell ;
```